# How do I tell Java to go to a specific row in a 2d array?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

For schoolwork, I need to write a class that is a matrix of integers. Its attribute is a 2-dimensional array which is meant to be squared. One of the methods has a parameter that is an int which is meant to refer to a specific "row" of the matrix. The method checks if that specific row, the one that was passed in with the method, has all the numbers in ascending order. For example, a number 6 would be passed in.  How do I tell Java to go to a "row"  or array 6 in the 2d array? The method signature is:
boolean checkIfAscending(int rowNumber, int size).

Comment: What do you mean by "go to"? It would help if you'd show some code (ideally a [mcve]) and explain what you're trying to achieve more clearly.

Comment: @JonSkeet if I am not sure how to write code how can I show code? I will try to edit my question to clarify, but I am not sure what is so unclear.

Comment: @Rehman arr[1] is not the first row.... it is the second row. In java arrays are zero based

Comment: You can give all the context needed, with an indication if where you need help. Currently we can't really tell what you have or what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply with the syntax `array[row][col]`;

For example to read all the elements in the first row:

```
int array[][] = ...

for (int x : array[0]) {
   // Loop through element of first row
}
```

Or to get third element of second row

```
int x = array[1][2];
```

Obviously you can do it also with variables (eventually parameters of a method):

```
int row = 1;
int column = 2;

int x = array[row][column];
```

Comment: That won't be really helping OP to become a better student.. He should first try things by himself.

Comment: It is a problem of syntax, not a conceptual problem, so if not found here he can found it in other ways. This is not a solution to a problem.

Comment: @MarounMaroun I am not even sure what to try. The OP can tell if something is helpful or not.

Answer (score 0):

```
int x = rows;
int y = cols;
int[][] = new int[rows][cols];
```

Then, to access a certain row, simply fill the first pair of brackets with an index value for that row.  Remember Java uses 0 based indexes, 5 rows would be numbered 0-4.

```
System.out.println("The value for the 3rd column in the 2nd row is: " + matrix[2-1][3-1]);
```

I deliberately used 2-1 and 3-1 because the indexes are zero based.  So, the second row is actually row 1 and the 3rd column is the second entry.

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean checkIfAscending(int array[][],int rowNumber){
    int row[] = array[rowNumber];
    for(int i = 0; i < row.length-1; i++){
        if(row[i] > row[i+1]){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```